# DB2 - Problem with a bogus estimated run time and SQL0666

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

I am trying to recreate address at a point in time based on current address and a log record of changes. We have a table with customer addresses in fields `line1` thorugh `line4`. Following is an approximation of the table and data:

```sql
create table qtemp.customers (
  id int,
  line1 char(40),
  line2 char(40),
  line3 char(40),
  line4 char(40));

insert into qtemp.customers (id, line1, line2, line3, line4)
with cust_temp(id, line1, line2, line3, line4) as(
  select 1, 'Line1', 'Line2', 'Line3', 'Line4'
  from sysibm.sysdummy1
  union all
  select id+1, line1, line2, line3, line4 from cust_temp where id<15000) 
select * from cust_temp;
```

Then we have a table with logged changes, including logs for changes for individual address lines. The type of changes I am interested in start with 'Line ' and number. They are mixed within other changes. Again a rough approximation of the table:

```sql
create table qtemp.changes (
  seq int,
  dt int,
  cid int,
  change_type char(40),
  change char(40));

insert into qtemp.changes (seq, dt, cid, change_type, change) 
with changes_temp(seq, dt, cid, change_type, change) as(
  select 1, 1, 1, 'not a real change', 'just a bogus line' from sysibm.sysdummy1
  union all
  select seq+1,
         dt + int(rand() + 0.005), --about 175 changes per day on average 
         int(rand() * 15000 + 1), 
         case int(rand() * 13) --little less then 3000 changes to address line
           when 1 then 'Line ' || int(rand() * 4 + 1)
           else trim(TRANSLATE ( CHAR(BIGINT(RAND() * 50 )), 'abcdefghij', '1234567890' )) || ' Some other change'
         end, 
         TRANSLATE ( CHAR(BIGINT(RAND() * 10000000000 )), 'abcdefghij', '1234567890' ) 
  from changes_temp where seq < 35000)
select * from changes_temp;
```

My solution to that was to select only `'Line%'` records, transpose them to corresponding `line1` thorugh `line4` columns and then use window function to fill in the nulls.

```sql
with
changes_filtered as (
  select * from changes
  where change_type like 'Line%'),
--only show the last change for any particular customer id, date and line
changes_latest as (
  select a.*
  from changes_filtered a 
  left join changes_filtered b on a.cid = b.cid and a.dt = b.dt and a.change_type = b.change_type and a.seq<b.seq
  where b.seq is null),
changes_pivoted as (
  select cid, dt, 
    max(case when change_type = 'Line 1' then change end) line1, 
    max(case when change_type = 'Line 2' then change end) line2, 
    max(case when change_type = 'Line 3' then change end) line3, 
    max(case when change_type = 'Line 4' then change end) line4
  from changes_latest
  group by cid, dt
  
  union all 
  
  select id, 99999, line1, line2, line3, line4 from customers
  where id in (select cid from changes_filtered)
  ),  
changes_filled as (
  select cid, dt,
     first_value(line1) ignore nulls over(partition by cid order by dt rows between current row and unbounded following) line1,
     first_value(line2) ignore nulls over(partition by cid order by dt rows between current row and unbounded following) line2,
     first_value(line3) ignore nulls over(partition by cid order by dt rows between current row and unbounded following) line3,
     first_value(line4) ignore nulls over(partition by cid order by dt rows between current row and unbounded following) line4
  from changes_pivoted
  )  
select * from changes_filled order by cid, dt;
```

However, when I try to run it, I immediately get following error

> [SQL0666] SQL query exceeds specified time limit or storage limit. Cause . . . . . :   A database query was about to be started whose **estimated** run time of 2147352576 exceeds the specified limit of 600

Notice the word **estimated**. This is a preemptive strike. The limit of 600 seconds is set via system value. If I override it with `CHGQRYA`, the query runs in 150ms. So the estimated runtime is totally bogus. When I look at visual explain, cumulative time for each OLAP grows exponentially. First estimated time is 1134s, second 4M s, third 1400M s, fourth 50000000M s.

I found this IBM document about [ODBC Query Timeout Property: SQL0666 Estimated Query Processing Time Exceeds Limit](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/odbc-query-timeout-property-sql0666-estimated-query-processing-time-exceeds-limit) stating that

> If the proper indexes are not in place, the estimate may be very poor
> (and the query may not perform well).

but 150ms vs 1.6M years is not even wrong. The query performs well, but the estimate is not even in this galaxy.

EDIT: I guess the question I am trying to ask is whether there is a solution to this problem without changing the system value for runtime (QQRYTIMLMT) and without building dedicated indexes just for this query.

EDIT2: Creating indexes has no effect. I tried to create indexes on my own as well as those suggested by index advisor and I experienced no difference in the estimated run time. I have a case opened with IBM.

```sql
CREATE INDEX QTEMP/CHANGES_IDX
  ON QTEMP/CHANGES (CID ASC, DT ASC) UNIT ANY KEEP IN MEMORY NO;
CREATE INDEX QTEMP/CHANGES_IDX2
  ON QTEMP/CHANGES (CHANGE_TYPE ASC, DT ASC, CID ASC) UNIT ANY KEEP IN MEMORY NO;
CREATE INDEX QTEMP/CUSTOMERS_IDX
  ON QTEMP/CUSTOMERS (ID ASC) UNIT ANY KEEP IN MEMORY NO;
CREATE INDEX QTEMP/CHANGES_IDX3
  ON QTEMP/CHANGES (CID ASC, CHANGE_TYPE ASC) UNIT ANY KEEP IN MEMORY NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, nope.

You've asked the system to prohibit queries based upon estimated run-times.  You'll either need to change the limit, or create the indexes or collect the statistics the system needs for a better estimate.

Having said that, you might check to see if you're up to date on PTFs and if not get current.

Once current, if you still see the way off estimates, you might open a case with IBM to have them look at it.   It could be a bug, or at the very least they may have a suggestion on what indexes or statistic you need to have to give the Db the ability to make a better estimate.

You might also try doing this as a stored procedure.  There's some plan information that gets store inside the stored procedure object that may help the system better estimate the run-time.  (just a thought, no idea if it's right.  IBM could tell you)

**EDIT**
The one suggestion I might make is to modify the `INSERT` so that only the `Line%` records are output, thus removing the need for the changes_filtered CTE.

You might also try adding the `OPTIMIZE FOR xx ROWS` clause to your `SELECT` statements to give the DB a better idea of how many rows you expect.

Comment: I tried OPTIMIZE FOR nn ROWS to no avail. Those inserts are there just to populate the temporary tables to make data distribution close to what I am looking at. For me the data is already there. I was thinking about creating a view that filters out just what I need and hiding that part from the optimizer, but I would like it to be self contained.I will look into PTFs and possibly submitting a case to IBM. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was able to cheat it by splitting the changes_filled CTE into four CTEs, one for each window function and joining them back together. It seem to prove that the estimate is broken for multiple windows in one select.

```sql
with
changes_filtered as (
  select * from changes
  where change_type like 'Line%'),
--only show the last change for any particular customer id, date and line
changes_latest as (
  select a.*
  from changes_filtered a 
  left join changes_filtered b on a.cid = b.cid and a.dt = b.dt and a.change_type = b.change_type and a.seq<b.seq
  where b.seq is null),
changes_pivoted as (
  select cid, dt, 
    max(case when change_type = 'Line 1' then change end) line1, 
    max(case when change_type = 'Line 2' then change end) line2, 
    max(case when change_type = 'Line 3' then change end) line3, 
    max(case when change_type = 'Line 4' then change end) line4
  from changes_latest
  group by cid, dt
  
  union all 
  
  select id, 99999, line1, line2, line3, line4 from customers
  where id in (select cid from changes_filtered)
  ),  
changes_filled1 as (
  select cid, dt,
     first_value(line1) ignore nulls over(partition by cid order by dt rows between current row and unbounded following) line1
  from changes_pivoted
  ),  
changes_filled2 as (
  select cid, dt,
     first_value(line2) ignore nulls over(partition by cid order by dt rows between current row and unbounded following) line2
  from changes_pivoted
  ),  
changes_filled3 as (
  select cid, dt,
     first_value(line3) ignore nulls over(partition by cid order by dt rows between current row and unbounded following) line3
  from changes_pivoted
  ),  
changes_filled4 as (
  select cid, dt,
     first_value(line4) ignore nulls over(partition by cid order by dt rows between current row and unbounded following) line4
  from changes_pivoted
  )  

select t1.cid, t1.dt, line1, line2, line3, line4 
from changes_filled1 t1
join changes_filled2 t2 on t1.cid = t2.cid and t1.dt = t2.dt
join changes_filled3 t3 on t1.cid = t3.cid and t1.dt = t3.dt
join changes_filled4 t4 on t1.cid = t4.cid and t1.dt = t4.dt
order by t1.cid, t1.dt;
```